# Program to create navigation (table of contents) for a video training

Tags: video-editing

I am creating a video training and I'm looking for a piece of software that would allow me to create table of contents / navigation menu for my training. It might be similar to what pluralsight does with their trainings.

As an input I have a video file that I can split into parts if needed.

Desired features:

- user can easily jump between video sections
- user can run my training without need to install additional software

  - html format is fine for me
  - assumed user will have web browser with flash/silverlight already installed
- I can pack whole training into single file (possibly just zip it) and send it to the user.
- program has to be available for free